# How to convert Array of Constants into String with the constant names and not its assigned values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
ABC = 'abc'
DEF = 'def'
XYZ = 'anything'
LIST_ALL = [ABC, DEF, XYZ]
```

If I do

```
LIST_ALL.reject(&:blank?).join(', ') # => "abc, def, anything"
```

What I am looking for is to get the constant names, not their values
Expected output:

```
LIST_ALL.something() #=> "ABC, DEF, XYZ"
```

Approach #1:

```
class X
  ABC = "abc"
  DEF = "def"
  GHI = ""
  XYZ = "anything"
  LIST_ALL = %w(ABC DEF GHI XYZ)

  def self.something()
     puts LIST_ALL.reject{|c| c.constantize.blank?}.join(', ')
     # puts LIST_ALL[0].constantize
  end
end
```

Error:

```
(NameError)  uninitialized constant ABC;
```

Comment: How about `LIST_ALL.map(&:upcase)` and after that apply join if you want string. like this `LIST_ALL.map(&:upcase).join(", ")`

Comment: @AjayBarot Sorry. upcase wont always work. This is just an example. Will update the question for better understandability that upcase won't always work. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the constant names as strings, when you want to check the constant value use `#constantize'...

```
ABC = 'abc'
DEF = 'def'
GHI = ''
XYZ = 'anything'
LIST_ALL = %w(ABC DEF GHI XYZ)
```

Then you can do...

```
LIST_ALL.reject{|c| c.constantize.blank?}.join(', ') # => "ABC, DEF, XYZ"
```

Comment: Can you also include how to use #constantize to get constants value when required?

Comment: Just use "#constantize" by itself.   `ABC =  "text"; my_constant = "ABC"` then `my_constant.constantize` will return "text"

Comment: `undefined method 'constantize' for "ABC":String
(repl):6:in 'block in <main>'
(repl):6:in 'reject'
(repl):6:in '<main>'` getting this error

Comment: I realized constantize is rails specific. On running using RoR, I am getting this error: `(NameError)  uninitialized constant ABC;` I have updated the question using your approach.

Comment: I have edited the answer. With more detailed implementation details. Thanks a ton for your answer. Also, my very first step to meta-programming.

Comment: Uninitialized constant?  You've defined the constant ABC before you attempted the `constantize`?

Comment: I have added my implementation details as another answer. It is working for me now. The constants needed to be as <class_name>::<constant_name> otherwise, was getting uninitialized constants.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby has no explicit hook for instance naming, as I can see. However, classes does.

```
CONSTANT = 'my constant value'
instance = Class.new
CONSTANT = instance
instance.name.to_s
=> "CONSTANT"
```

Unfortunately, this will mess with your constant value, and that's not what you want.

In any case, a solution I see is to stop using constants directly and use a hash. Just like:

```
MY_HASH  = { 'ABC' => 'abc', 'DEF' => 'def' }
puts "constant names are #{MY_HASH.keys.join(', ')}"
=> "constant names are ABC, DEF"

puts "constant values are #{MY_HASH.values.join(', ')}"
=> "constant values are abc, def"
```

If you still wanna mess with metaprogramming, [**check this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13300489/6241184).

Comment: vnbrs@ Map seems overkill for my purpose. I am building up LIST_ALL just to use it to validate that it is a valid input. And the valid inputs are ABC, DEF, XYZ

Comment: You don't need `map` if you build the hash using the old syntax. `{ 'ABC' => 'abc', 'DEF' => 'def' }`

Comment: LIST_ALL should be the list of constants i.e ABC, DEF and XYZ. Not in string. Later, I want to concatenate like `"constant names are: " + LIST_ALL.something()` which should then give output as `constant names are: ABC, DEF, XYZ`

Comment: I made a change @AayushKumarSingha

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my implementation part, I have less inclination to use a map. Since, every other place its done this way. Making it consistent. I am looking more ways if possible.

Comment: I removed the map @AayushKumarSingha

Answer (score 0):

Implementation details inside a class.
Add `<classname>::<constant_name>` otherwise throws (NameError) uninitialized Constant ABC:

```
class X
  ABC = "123"
  DEF = "456"
  LIST_ALL = %w(X::ABC X::DEF)

  def something()
    puts LIST_ALL.reject{|c| c.constantize.blank?}.join(', ') # output: X::ABC, X::DEF
    puts LIST_ALL[0].constantize # output: 123
  end
end
```

Note: to use constantize, Ruby on Rails is pre-requisite.